# The perception of /ɑ/ and /a/

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

The  [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barn) transcription for the word barn is **/bɑːrn/**

If someone says this word as /baːrn/ (open front vowel), will this sound foreign to you? Will you notice at all? What will your thoughts be on the speech of a person who changes his **/ɑ/**'s with **/a/**'s in words like this?

[Wikipedia phonetic alphabet; vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Vowels)

I'm not sure what I'm doing but here's me saying **/bɑːrn/**. and then **/baːrn/** : [Vocaroo speech example](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1ZkK3fV8rXN)

Can you try it yourself as native speakers?

Comment: As a note to ELU voters. A nearly-identical question has already been asked and closed on ELL, so if you VTC, please don't vote to migrate to ELL.

Comment: If somebody says it like /baːrn/ to me, they sound as if they grew up in Boston or thereabouts. But then, I live near Boston; I don't know what it sounds like to Californians or Brits.

Comment: American English does not distinguish between those vowels, especially before /r/.

Comment: Why do people argue about thread closing in the threads itself? Don't you have a moderator lounge or something?

Comment: @Hey No, there is no moderator lounge, and closing questions is not usually done by moderators, but by fellow members (none of the people who have commented on this question is a moderator). We also don't have threads here, but questions and answers. I suggest taking the [tour].  As for your question, I'm afraid it's rather subjective, which makes it off-topic—if you can find a way to rephrase it so that it can be said to have an authoritatively correct answer, it can be made on-topic. (For the record, I'd think someone who says [baːɹn] was saying _bairn_, rather than _barn_.)

Comment: It's even worse that you're not moderators. This forum has "usage" in it's name. Usage is subjective, so no, it's not off-topic. And yes, it is a thread, a thread of comments.

Comment: To answer your question: it's not standard English; it's noticeably different. As I said, it's one of the distinctive features of some New England accents. And Janus would think it was a different word entirely.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterShor. Your answer differs from John Lawler. Can you comment on his answer? Is he incorrect?

Comment: Another thing. These tables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Vowels show that English doesn't have /a/ sound. But this symbol (/a/) is used with diphthongs. What does it mean?

Comment: Americans don't really use /a/; it's halfway between /ɑ/ and /æ/, and it could be taken for either one of these vowels, so it's best to avoid it. Some New England speakers use /ar/ instead of /ɑr/ in words like *car* and *barn*, but I don't really understand the details so I won't go into it.

Comment: As for diphthongs, English speakers don't think of them as a combination of two vowels but as a separate phoneme of their own. The diphthong /ɔɪ/ is not perceived as /ɔ/ followed by /ɪ/. So the vowels in *cawing* /kɔɪŋ/ are not pronounced the same as the diphthong in *coin* /kɔɪn/. At least, not by me. And many Americans really do pronounce *rice* something like /raɪs/. Unlike Australians, who distinguish between /rɑɪs/ (*rice*) and /ræɪs/ (*race*). [See this webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects).

Comment: @PeterShor **The diphthong /ɔɪ/ is not perceived as /ɔ/ followed by /ɪ/. So the vowels in cawing /kɔɪŋ/ are not pronounced the same as the diphthong in coin /kɔɪn/. At least, not by me.** What's the difference in pronunciation of these vowels in these two words?

Comment: There's not much difference. On the vowel chart, my *coin* would be slightly left and above my *cawing*. But I am sure this varies a lot between speakers, and I don't think it's something anybody would notice when you're speaking. It's not something you should worry about.